# Kendo textbox within dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, kendo-ui

is possible to make textbox within the dropdownlist from Kendo? When user won't find on list what he needs, there should be textbox to set manually some value.

dropdown:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("Id")
.DataTextField("StringValue")
.DataValueField("Id")
.SelectedIndex(0))
```

javascript:

```
$('#AttributeValue_Id').kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        dataTextField: "Text",
        dataValueField: "Value",
        optionLabel: '@Html.Raw(T("Product.Attribute.SelectValue"))',
        dataBound: function () {
            $('#AttributeValue_Id').data('kendoDropDownList').select(0);
        }
    });
```

Values in this dropdown depend on another dropdown, where we pick attribute and then this dropdown is getting new data dynamically. Somebody know any solution?

Comment: Could you not use a AutoComplete instead, and just get the value from that? https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/autocomplete or a Combobox https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/combobox

Comment: I'm tryin do something like here:
https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/addnewitem
I'm getting button with "Add new value", but i don't have idea how to change this code for my needs. After click this button I need redirect to add action from controller. Anyway when I use this code, $(document).ready is ruin another javascripts. Can somebody explain me how to do it?

Comment: The link you sent is pure jQuery editing of the dropdown, not the asp.net mvc version you are using. I'm sure you could hack a way to this (which is often the case with Kendo), but alternatively you could use something simple like the Autocomplete and save it to the source of the data when the form is submitted (if you're doing it for reuse purposes).

Comment: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/dropdownlist

Comment: There is no ready to use code for this. You'll have to custamize as per your needs. This might help you. https://www.telerik.com/forums/server-filtering-and-adding-new-item-in-combobox

Comment: Also, you can take help from https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/addnewitem where you can fire an ajax request for MVC Controller action on the click of 'Add item' button and refresh the widget for client side making sure they are in sync

Answer (score 2):

Ok I solved this issue. Solution is:
when the element on dropdown filter is not exist, I can write my string value and redirect to AddNew function. Javascript for no data template:

```
<script id="noDataTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-tmpl">
<div>
    Didn't find the element
</div>
<br />
<button class="k-button" onclick="addNew('#: instance.element[0].id #', '#: instance.filterInput.val() #')">Add new value</button>
```

AddNew function is get widget element and my value. If user will confirm the script will redirect to action from controller sending needed values - productId from Model, value from parameter and attributeDefinitionId value from first dropdown:

```
function addNew(widgetId, value) {
    var widget = $("#" + widgetId).getKendoDropDownList();
    var attributeDefinition = $('#AttributeDefinition').data('kendoDropDownList').value();
    var dataSource = widget.dataSource;

    if (confirm("Are you sure?")) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddAttributeValue", "Product")' + '?productId=@Model.Id' + '&value=' + value + '&attributeDefinition=' + attributeDefinition,
            cache: false,
        }).done(function () {
            var grid = $("#attributesGrid").data("kendoGrid");
            grid.dataSource.read();
        });

        dataSource.one("sync", function () {
            widget.select(dataSource.view().length - 1);
        });

        dataSource.sync();
    }
};
```

In controller I'm getting these values and insert them to database:

```
public ActionResult AddAttributeValue(int productId, string value, int attributeDefinition)
    {

        if (value != null)
        {
            try
            {
                var model = attributeValueRepository.Insert(new ProductAttributeValue()
                {
                    IsCustom = true,
                    StringValue = value,
                    AttributeDefinitionId = attributeDefinition,
                });

                productAttributeRepository.Insert(new ProductAttribute()
                {
                    AttributeValueId = model.Id,
                    ProductId = productId
                });
            } catch
            {
                AddErrorFlashMessage(T("Product.Attribute.AttributeValueError"));
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```

## Edit

Almost forgot, I set also on dropDown noDataTemplate:

```
        $('#AttributeValue_Id').kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: dataSource,
        dataTextField: "Text",
        dataValueField: "Value",
        optionLabel: '@Html.Raw(T("Product.Attribute.SelectValue"))',
        filter: "startswith",
        noDataTemplate: $("#noDataTemplate").html(),
        dataBound: function () {
            $('#AttributeValue_Id').data('kendoDropDownList').select(0);
        }
    });
```

Thanks everybody for the tips

Answer (score 0):

Might be late for an answer but kendo dropdownlist supports `contains` filter for exactly this workflow.

```
<%= Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("DropDownList")
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains);
%>
```

Ref: [Kendo UI Dropdownlist API](https://docs.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/api/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/DropDownListBuilder?_ga=2.87007963.2142243968.1637607795-1721825335.1618324560)

Answer (score 0):

Kendo already have feature within Dropdownlist in case user unable to find his choice option. He can add new element manually in dropdownlist. Please find link below

https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/addnewitem